# Yii "select2 (autocomplete)" widget does not work after Ajax

Tags: ajax, yii, autocomplete, widget, jquery-select2

Use this widget http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/.

Without using Ajax request widget works.
If the widget has been called in the main view, all works. If the widget is called with Ajax - widget does not work.
Widget does not work after ajax:
i have:

Controller:

```
public function actionDynamicwidget(){
  if (Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest)
  {
$content = $this->render('_ajaxContent', null); //Additional view
    Yii::app()->end();
   }    
}
```

View (main view):

```
<div id="city_region_row"></div>
<? echo CHtml::ajaxLink(
    CHtml::image('/images/plus.png', '', array(
        'id' => 'plus'  
    )),
    $url = CController::createUrl('Controller/Dynamicwidget'), 
    $ajaxOptions=array (
        'type'=>'POST',                 
        'success'=>'function(data){
                       $("#city_region_row").append(data);
                     }'
    ), 
    $htmlOptions=array ()
);
```

view: (_ajaxContent) //Additional view

```
<input type="hidden" value="1" id="regid1"/><?
$this->widget('ext.ESelect2.ESelect2', array(
'selector' => '#regid1',
'options' => array(     
    'ajax'=>
    array(
      'url'=>CController::createUrl('/PromouterCity/autoComplete'),
      'dataType'=>'json',
      'data'     => 'js: function(term,page) {
                                   return {
                                     q: term,
                             };
            }',
      'results'  => 'js: function(data,page){
                return {results: data};
            }',
        ),
    'formatResult'       => 'js:function(data){
                var markup = data.name;
                return markup;
             }',
            'formatSelection'    => 'js: function(data, container) {
                                                    return data.name;
            }',     
),
```

));

Comment: what's the error you get ?

Comment: " Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'select2' ". Looking for a solution on the Internet, nothing found

Comment: I had this issue before, I had to call the select2 jquery plugin after each time the ajax call is done.

Comment: KraneBird, thx. It works